# Has the way the way the Shader to RGB node functions changed in 3.2?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

So I'm using the 3.2 alpha, and was working on my comic which I do with a toon-esque render. But then, I noticed that my bump maps weren't functioning properly. After much tinkering, I tracked it down to the Shader to RGB node. And it seemed quite odd, so I did a simple test:

[image: Test Image with Blender 3.2 without the Shader to RGB node]

There, I have a grayscale image with some doodles to do the bump map, and coming from the Diffuse node, it looks fine. However:

[image: Test Image with Blender 3.2 using the Shader to RGB node]

As soon as I throw in the Shader to RGB node, the bumps that had been there previously vanish. At first, I thought I might have just made some sort of mistake with my setup, so I tested it in Blender 3.1, but it works as it should:

[image: Test Image with Blender 3.1]

So my question is, will the Shader to RGB node be deprecated in 3.2? Or is this just a temporary quirk with it still being an alpha? Or perhaps, am I doing something completely wrong which is why it's not working properly?

Comment: As of today's 3.2.0 beta ( f11dba88923f ) the same is happening when I tried it.  I've found no indication this is intended behavior -- you might've found a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post by searching the same problem: I had a shader to RGB node in 3.2 beta and it didn't work as intended, but opening the same setup in 3.1 (and 2.8 I had kicking around) did work.

downloaded a fresh copy of 3.6 and it works again, so it's something about that exact build.